# NoClassDefFoundError after importing aar file - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to use a customed aar file in my project.

so, I added dependencies to "build.gradle" file.

Here is my "build.gradle" file.

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0"
  compile "com.test:custom:0.0.1@aar
}
```

And, here is the java file that I used the activity of the customed aar.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(MyProjectActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(sharingIntent);
```

When I compiled this project, there was no problem and "AndroidManifest.xml" file was merged well. 
However, when I runed the application, an error occured and it terminated.

Here is the error message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.custom.MainActivity
        at com.project.MyProjectActivity.onRecommendClick(MyProjectActivity.java)
```

The problem is that the apk included resource files without classes.jar.

How can I include the classes.jar of aar into the apk?

Comment: I guess u forgoted to check the library in build path in order and export tab. please select those librarys in that tab.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I've just checked the issue tracker of android.

Here is the url. 
[Issue 55863](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=55863)

It doesn't support yet.